# How to run background service listen to realtime database flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, localnotification

I need to run background service to listen to firebase realtime database and trigger local notifications on change in flutter app

Answer (score 0):

Native mobile platform such as iOS and Android, actively work against such background listeners as they drain the battery in a way that the OS can't control (on behalf of the user). So while you may be able to start listening in a background process, the OS will kill the socket connection used for that listener quickly (in 5m on recent Android versions).

The proper way to notify the user of activity in the database while they're not actively using the app is to set a listener in an always-on environment, and then use Firebase Cloud Messaging and/or APNS to send a notification to the affected user(s).

If you don't have a server you control yet, you can use Cloud Functions through Firebase to get started. For an example of this, see the [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) use-case in the Firebase docs and the code sample linked from there.

> [image]
>
> 1. The function triggers on writes to the Realtime Database path where followers are stored.
> 2. The function composes a message to send via FCM.
> 3. FCM sends the notification message to the user's device.